# Genetic algorithm techniques for allocation of electric vehicles

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

The problem I'm trying to solve is about the best allocation for electric vehicles (EVs) in the electrical power grid. My grid has 20 possible positions (busbar) allowed to receive one EV each. Each chromosome has length 20 and its genes can be 0 or 1, where 0 means no EV and 1 means there´s an EV at that position (busbar).

I start my population (100 individuals) with a fixed number of EVs (5, for instance) allocated randomly. And let them evolve through my GA. The GA utilizes tournament selection, 2-points crossover and flip-bit mutation. Each chromosome/individual is evaluated through a fitness function that calculate the power losses between bars (sum of RI^2). The best chromosome is the one with the lowest power losses.

The problem is that utilizing 2-points crossover and flip-bit mutation changes the fixed number of EVs that must be in the grid. I would like to know what are the best techniques for my GA operations. Besides this, I get this weird looking graphic of the most fitness chromosome throughout generations [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVlit.png)

I would appreciate any help/suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to define your state space in such a way where the mutations you've chosen can't create an illegal configuration.

This is probably not a great fit for a genetic algorithm. If you want to pick 5 from 20, there are ~15k possibilities. Testing a population of 100 over 50 generations already gives you enough computations to have done 1/3 of the brute force work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have N EV to assign on your grid, you can use chromosomes of size N, each gene being an integer representing the position of an EV. For the crossover, you first need to separate the values that are the same in both parents from the rest and apply a classic (1 or 2 points) crossover on the parts that differ, and mutate a gene randomly picking a valid available position.